# Rails two factor authentication when user signing up with phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, two-factor-authentication

I have implemented two factor authentication using the following gem.

https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication

Documentation is simple and clear. This works fine when users tries to sign in. But when signing up the below action in **user.rb** is not working.

```
def send_two_factor_authentication_code(code)
end
```

*code in the above is the generated OTP*

https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication

How can i make the above action works when user is signing up too?

Comment: Could you tell us what your error message is?

Comment: After signing up where you are redirecting the user, login page ? or user logging into the system?

if you are directing into to login page then send_two_factor_authentication_code method will not trigger, it will trigger only after successful login

Comment: @SivaKB By default, rails devise gem will let user log in after signing up. This bypasses login action so the "send_two_factor_authentication_code" is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a OP of this question, I have followed this simple solution below to implement this and it works perfectly.

https://www.mccartie.com/tech/2015/10/20/sms-verification.html